# Calculating minutes within a specific time period for each session in R

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, lubridate

This is the sample dataset.

```
StartTime   EndTime User
5/18/2023 2:40  5/18/2023 4:44  FJNDS
5/18/2023 4:04  5/18/2023 5:07  DFDSFDS
5/18/2023 5:07  5/18/2023 5:13  CXXZVC
5/18/2023 1:40  5/18/2023 5:41  SAFDSFD
5/18/2023 1:40  5/18/2023 5:41  VCXZVXC
5/18/2023 4:31  5/19/2023 5:47  VDSFSDFD
```

Each row corresponds to one session. I want to find out if any of the session falls between 3:00 to 6:00 time period. If any session/row falls between that time period, then the number of minutes within that time period needs to be noted separately in a column.

Note that in the last row (user id == VDSFSDFD), the session is between two days. So in this case, the total minutes between the 3:00 to 6:00 time period needs to be noted for two days.

Can it be done using lubridate in R ? Other R functions also would be okay for me.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Calculate the interval using `interval()`, the hour using `hour()`, then use an if else to calculate the minutes using `time_length(interval, "minutes")` when the hour falls between 3 and 6.

Comment: @Quinten                     `df <- data.frame(
  StartTime = c("5/18/2023 2:40", "5/18/2023 4:04", "5/18/2023 5:07", "5/18/2023 1:40", "5/18/2023 1:40", "5/18/2023 4:31"),
  EndTime = c("5/18/2023 4:44", "5/18/2023 5:07", "5/18/2023 5:13", "5/18/2023 5:41", "5/18/2023 5:41", "5/19/2023 5:47"),
  User = c("FJNDS", "DFDSFDS", "CXXZVC", "SAFDSFD", "VCXZVXC", "VDSFSDFD")
)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(   StartTime = c("5/18/2023 2:40", "5/18/2023 4:04", "5/18/2023 5:07", "5/18/2023 1:40", "5/18/2023 1:40", "5/18/2023 4:31"),   EndTime = c("5/18/2023 4:44", "5/18/2023 5:07", "5/18/2023 5:13", "5/18/2023 5:41", "5/18/2023 5:41", "5/19/2023 5:47"),   User = c("FJNDS", "DFDSFDS", "CXXZVC", "SAFDSFD", "VCXZVXC", "VDSFSDFD") )
```

Convert the StartTime and EndTime columns to the appropriate
datetime format using the `as.POSIXct` function:

```
df$StartTime <- as.POSIXct(df$StartTime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
df$EndTime <- as.POSIXct(df$EndTime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

Create a new column called MinutesInRange and assign it a value of 0
for all rows:

```
df$MinutesInRange <- 0
```

Handle cases where the session spans 2 days  :

```
df$MinutesInRange <- as.numeric(ifelse(round(as.numeric(difftime(df$EndTime, df$StartTime, units = "days"))) >= 1,
                                       abs(as.numeric(difftime(df$StartTime, as.POSIXct(paste0(format(df$StartTime, "%Y-%m-%d"), " 06:00:00")), units = "mins"))),
                                       0)+
                                  ifelse(round(as.numeric(difftime(df$EndTime, df$StartTime, units = "days"))) >= 1,
                                         abs(as.numeric(difftime(df$EndTime, as.POSIXct(paste0(format(df$EndTime, "%Y-%m-%d"), " 03:00:00")), units = "mins"))),
                                         0))
```

Handle the rest of cases by using the `ifelse` function to check if each session falls within the
time period of 3:00 to 6:00. If it does, calculate the number of
minutes within that time period and assign it to the MinutesInRange column:

```
df$MinutesInRange <- ifelse(
  format(df$StartTime, "%H:%M") >= "03:00" & format(df$EndTime, "%H:%M") <= "06:00",
  as.numeric(difftime(df$EndTime, df$StartTime, units = "mins")),
  df$MinutesInRange
)
```

And this is the result:

```
 df
            StartTime             EndTime     User MinutesInRange
1 2023-05-18 02:40:00 2023-05-18 04:44:00    FJNDS              0
2 2023-05-18 04:04:00 2023-05-18 05:07:00  DFDSFDS             63
3 2023-05-18 05:07:00 2023-05-18 05:13:00   CXXZVC              6
4 2023-05-18 01:40:00 2023-05-18 05:41:00  SAFDSFD              0
5 2023-05-18 01:40:00 2023-05-18 05:41:00  VCXZVXC              0
6 2023-05-18 04:31:00 2023-05-19 05:47:00 VDSFSDFD            256
```

Comment: The total minutes and Minutes_Within_Period are going wrong !
For example, the toatal minutes in the first session in your example is between  2023-06-15 10:02:13 and 2023-06-15 10:10:45, for which the total minutes should be 8, rather the result is showing 1817 minutes in total and 17 mins in minutes within_period column.

Apart from this my actual requirement was to calculate the minutes within a certain time period like 3:00 AM to  6:00 AM. If the session doesnt fall between this time frame, then we need to assign 0.

Comment: @Thaatha_Paati I have changed my previous response now that you provided the data. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Great ! Its very helpfull. Thank you. 
But if you look at the 6th row, the total minutes within 3:00 am to 6:am is very high. It should have been ideally, ~ 1.5 hrs (90 min) for 18th May and ~ 3hrs for 19th May. So the total mins should have been nearly 270 minutes.

Comment: @Thaatha_Paati Based on the data and information you provided, I have made some changes to accommodate cases where the session spans over two days.